# Given an area (eg, a city), how can one assess the percentage of tourists it contains?

Tags: tourism

I sometimes wonder whether an area (eg, a city) has many tourists. How can one assess the percentage of tourists there is in a given area? I know it varies over time but just to get a vague approximation of how touristy an area is.

Comment: Hotels in many countries need to give some values (either registration, or number of people and nights to statistical authorities). Sometime you must pay a tourism tax. Nothing precise (not all hotel guesses are tourists, and there are many day tourism). Sometime there are extra surveys. I think usually the data is inflated.

Comment: If you want an average over the year, find the number of visitors and relate it to the number of residents. There are lots of caveats, though: visitor vs tourist (other visitors may include business, conventions…), number days they stay (in some cases you may be able to find number of nights, but some places have a lot of day trips), and of course you may have to look up lots of different sources.

Comment: There are no centralised statistics, but often you see reports on the tourist population of an area. For areas which attract a lot of tourists, there are often quite detailed statistics on visitor numbers. I suggest Googling: in particular at statistics by tourist authorities or market research companies (although the latter's figures may not be free). You may also be able to get a breakdown according to how many are there for business, or leisure tourism, or other reasons. Although people staying with relatives may not be counted.

Comment: Any stats for the average number of tourists is going to be misleading if a particular location hosts a well known major event every year, or has a distinct on season/off season, or even whether you are there mid-week or weekend.  What matters is not how touristy a place is in general, but how touristy a place is when you are there.

Comment: @PeterM the percentage of tourists there is in a given area can be expressed as a function of time.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to you, but I only notice an area being "touristy" when it's the percentage that is high, not the absolute number. Finding out how many local residents visit an area, to calculate the percentage, but might be harder.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt And because each city is different, has different attractions, has different seasons etc, you still need to research such information for the *particular* city you are visiting - making a generic solution of very limited value.  EG The chances of getting a room near Columbus circle NYC will be near zero on TG compared to spring - even though the number of hotels has not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas from the comment section: look at the statistics by tourist authorities or market research companies.

Other ideas:

1. search for "Hotel" on Google Maps and see the hotel density.
2. look for Wikipedia pages on tourism in a given location, e.g. [Tourism in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_the_United_States) or [Tourism in New York City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_New_York_City).

---

Original comments:

> - There are no centralised statistics, but often you see reports on the tourist population of an area. For areas which attract a lot of tourists, there are often quite detailed statistics on visitor numbers. I suggest Googling: in particular at statistics by tourist authorities or market research companies (although the latter's figures may not be free). You may also be able to get a breakdown according to how many are there for business, or leisure tourism, or other reasons. Although people staying with relatives may not be counted. [Stuart F](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/85309/stuart-f) [12 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177718/given-an-area-eg-a-city-how-can-one-assess-the-percentage-of-tourists-it-con#comment448479_177718)

Comment: Looking at hotels excludes day visitors. That will give huge distortions between holiday destinations like Benidorm and public attraction places like Lourdes.

Comment: Venice is maybe an extreme case: [CBS news](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/venice-unveils-mandatory-day-trippers-reservation-and-fee/) claims that "Roughly four-fifths of all tourists visit Venice just for the day." But the [tourism department](https://www.comune.venezia.it/sites/comune.venezia.it/files/immagini/Turismo/Adt19%20ing%20ver%204%201%202021%281%29.pdf) (p. 162) conducted a survey among registered visitors to the official tourist website that found that 94% of all visitors were staying overnight...